# miktex doesn't typeset long outlines in Windows 8

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, miktex

I have generated exported a tex document from emacs org mode.  The outline is rather long - 81 lines with five levels.   The exported latex file is typeset to pdf.  The TOC comes out fine, but the document has several blank pages and several pages where the text runs off the bottom.  Short outlines of 20 lines or so are typeset perfectly, but long outlines regularly drop pages.   I am running miktex on Windows 8 64 bit version.

Ok Here is the org outline file (simplified one character per heading):

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil   


* A
* B
* C
* D
* E
* F
* G
* H
* I
* J
* K
* L
* M
* N
* O
* P
* Q
* R
* S
* T
* U
* V
* W
* X
* Y
* Z
* a
* b
```

Now - the above SHOULD export to TEX as is. I type C-c C-e l o - Here is the LaTeX export:

```
% Created 2015-03-07 Sat 15:27
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\date{\today}
\title{testOutline}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{A}
\label{sec-1}
\section{B}
\label{sec-2}
\section{C}
\label{sec-3}
\section{D}
\label{sec-4}
\section{E}
\label{sec-5}
\section{F}
\label{sec-6}
\section{G}
\label{sec-7}
\section{H}
\label{sec-8}
\section{I}
\label{sec-9}
\section{J}
\label{sec-10}
\section{K}
\label{sec-11}
\section{L}
\label{sec-12}
\section{M}
\label{sec-13}
\section{N}
\label{sec-14}
\section{O}
\label{sec-15}
\section{P}
\label{sec-16}
\section{Q}
\label{sec-17}
\section{R}
\label{sec-18}
\section{S}
\label{sec-19}
\section{T}
\label{sec-20}
\section{U}
\label{sec-21}
\section{V}
\label{sec-22}
\section{W}
\label{sec-23}
\section{X}
\label{sec-24}
\section{Y}
\label{sec-25}
\section{Z}
\label{sec-26}
\section{a}
\label{sec-27}
\section{b}
\label{sec-28}
% Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)
\end{document}
```

looks ok to me - but what do i know? :-)  The pdf that results -

page one - title page with the file name testOutline and date March 7, 2015 -

page two blank -

page three  has headings 1 through 23 with letters A through W but the rest of the headings X through Z and a and b are missing - apparently off the bottom of the page.

### here is a screen shot:

### whoops - i need at least 10 reputation to post images so you'll have to take my word for it.

Here is a text representation of the resulting pdf page 3

1 A

2 B

3 C

4 D

5 E

6 F

7 G

8 H

9 I

10 J

11 K

12 L

13 M

14 N

15 O

16 P

17 Q

18 R

19 S

20 T

21 U

22 V

23 W

---------- end of page 3----------------
Chris - I'm VERY appreciative of your trying to answer my earlier attempts at a question.   Hopefully you'll see this.

### -Charlie

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer if you can't provide [an example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: OK - Here is the org-mode subtree:

Comment: org-mode file: * A <ret> * B ... * Z 26 lines

Comment: LaTeX export:
% Created ddd
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 "  [T1]{fontenc}
 "  {fixltx2e}
 "  {graphicx}
 "  {longtable}
 "  {float}
 "  {wrapfig}
 "  {rotating}
 "  [normalem]{ulem}
 "  {amsmath}
 "  {textcomp}
 "  {marvosym}
 "  {wasysym}
 "  {amssymb}
 "  {hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\date{\today}
\title{testOutline}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A}
\label{sec-1}
...
\section{Z}
\label{sec-26}
% Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)
\end{document}

Comment: problem: pdf output has a title page, a blank page and a page with sections A through W numbered 1 to 23.  X, Y Z and everything else apparently bleeds off the end of the page.   What can i do to fix it?

Comment: sorry, I don't have a web page to show code.

Comment: It is very hard to read this kind of content in comments. Instead, please edit your question and add the code directly to the question body.